# Laravel command cannot call $this->info() in child class

Tags: php, laravel, class-constructors

I'm just starting out with the basic concepts OO in PHP,

**Foo.php**

```
class Foo extends Command {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        $bar = new Bar();
    }

}
```

**Bar.php**

```
class Bar extends Foo {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->info('Bar');

    }
}
```

When I run `Foo::fire()` it gives: `Call to undefined method Foo::__construct()`. But `Foo` clearly has a constructor, what am I doing wrong?

Another thing I suspect is that it might be a Laravel problem rather than PHP. This is an `artisan` command that I created.

EDIT:

Also calling `$this->info('Bar')` anywhere in `Bar` will also give `Call to a member function writeln() on a non-object`. Why can't I call a parent's method from the child class?

Comment: This was a better approach for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122816/470749 And I'm also now investigating https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064494/470749 to see if that is the best way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I also ran into this issue, and felt Marcin's feedback to be cold and unhelpful, especially in his comments. For that I am happy to respond with this answer to you and anyone else who stumbles on this problem.

In the original class Bar:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->info('Bar');
    }
}
```

I just needed to set the property of 'output' like the following:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
        $this->info('Bar');
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I found `use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;` at the top of the file and then `$this->output = new ConsoleOutput;` worked for me

Comment: It'd be great if Laravel actually checked that there was no `$output` object and gave an appropriate error message, instead of just letting PHP throw an error. Especially since this is new behavior.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem today (11th November 2019) in a Laravel 6 (6.4) project, and this solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: THe solution seems appropriate but why not use DI instead of instanciating ConsoleOutput in construc()?