# Laravel Call the methods of a Artisan Command from a Parent Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

I was wondering if you could help me with the problem that I found a few hours ago and I have not been able to solve it. I happen to be trying to develop a small package in `Laravel`. This package will contain several `commands`, but for now I need those `commands` to inherit some methods and properties from a `parent class`. I have defined the following structure in my project:

```
package
├── composer.json
└── src
    ├── Commands
    │   └── ACommand.php
    │   └── BCommand.php
    ├── Package.php
    └── PackageServiceProvider.php
```

I register the commands inside the `PackageServiceProvider` as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Author\Package;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The commands to be registered.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \Author\Package\Commands\ACommand::class,
        \Author\Package\Commands\BCommand::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->commands($this->commands);
    }
}
```

Let's take the `ACommand` command as an example, it contains the following very basic structure to be brief:

```
<?php

namespace Author\Package\Commands;

use Author\Package\Package;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ACommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle(Package $package)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the `handle()` method I do `dependency injection` to the `Package` class. This is the content of the `Package` class:

```
<?php

namespace Author\Package;

use Illuminate\Console\Concerns\InteractsWithIO;

class Package
{
    use InteractsWithIO;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->info("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

when I run the command:

```
php artisan command:name
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Call to a member function writeln() on null
```

### What other kinds of things have I tried?

1. Create a `base command` and `extend` the other commands to that `class`, it would be as follows:

```
package
├── composer.json
└── src
    ├── Commands
    │   └── ACommand.php
    │   └── BCommand.php
    │   └── BaseCommand.php
    └── PackageServiceProvider.php
```

Let's take the `ACommand` command as an example here:

```
<?php

namespace Author\Package\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ACommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

...
```

the content of `BaseCommand` in this case I have left it like this:

```
<?php

namespace Author\Package\Commands;

use Author\Package\Package;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

abstract class BaseCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->info("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and I get the same error as a result:

```
Call to a member function writeln() on null
```

- *Also setting the `BaseCommand` class as `concrete` and not as `abstract` I get the same error.*

Basically for now what I need is to do almost all my logic from the `__construct()` method in a parent class .. and leave the result in a `property`. Then from a `child class`, access that `property`, since all my commands are going to use that property .. but each one of them is going to do something different with that property.. But it happens that I have not been able to execute statements as I would in a simple `command`, even when the `parent class` extends from the class: `Illuminate\Console\Command`.

As you can see in the example I am basically trying to display a message in the terminal called from the `parent class` when the `command` is executed. But I have not succeeded.
I have not done `Dependency Injection` from the `__construct()` method for the following reason:

[All artisan command constructors are fired when running any artisan command...what?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/all-artisan-command-constructors-are-fired-when-running-any-artisan-commandwhat)

[Change artisan console to only fire constructors for the command being called](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1399)

As you can see, when `Dependency Injection` is done in the `__construct()` method of a `command`, it is executed in any other `command`, that is why the documentation advises to do this `Dependency Injection` in the `handle()` method.

[Command Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#command-structure)

I have also read something here, but it has not served me much:

[Laravel command cannot call $this->info() in child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698122/laravel-command-cannot-call-this-info-in-child-class)

Please if someone expert on the subject could help me. Basically I am trying here, to call methods of the child class (`ACommand`) from the parent class (`Package`). I would appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try set output before `$this->info(..)`

```
...
$this->output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
$this->info()
...
```

The output does not appear to be set because your writeln error is probably in `src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/InteractsWithIO.php`:

```
    public function line($string, $style = null, $verbosity = null)
    {
        $styled = $style ? "<$style>$string</$style>" : $string;

        $this->output->writeln($styled, $this->parseVerbosity($verbosity));
    }
```

Comment: hi do you have the same solution to use ->confirm() and other methods ? thanks